# How can I insert into two tables in different SQL Server 2008 databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Example from pic.

http://pic.free.in.th/id/d56133ad2238308e979aa3dbea94436e

i want to insert data into Database A table A and Database B Table B in same time but some column from table A to Table B

EX.

table A have column ID,Name,Address,tel.I want just insert data ID,Name into table B.
(insert data to table B automaticly when insert data to table A )
if you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: Please post your whole question here - don't just link off to another site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an insert with a SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO DataBaseB.dbo.TableB (ID, Name)
SELECT ID, Name from DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
```

See here for more details:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

This assumes both databases are on the same server, if not, you could always export/import the data?

Comment: your answer it ok but i want to insert data to table B automaticly when insert data to table A .You have any idea?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a trigger with AFTER INSERT and then code to insert into TableB, google the use and look here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I create trigger like this

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ticky2] 
   ON  [dbo].[data]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
INSERT INTO [testDatabase].[dbo].[Sheet1$]
           ([ID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[salary]
           ,[date])
     SELECT ID, Name,salary,date from deconc.dbo.data

 after i execute 

Sheet1$ => (10 row(s) affected)
----i just want one row not all row from table data.

data => (1 row(s) affected).

please Recommend.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ticky2] 
   ON  [dbo].[data]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
INSERT INTO [testDatabase].[dbo].[pool]
           ([ID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[salary]
           ,[date])
     SELECT ID, Name,salary,date from deconc.dbo.data
     where ID not in 
     (

     select ID
     from [testDatabase].[dbo].[pool]

     )
```

Comment: For this code up there. I don't sure about performence.When transection Increase more and more.

Comment: Ah yes, you don't want to do that really, you can access the 'row' that was inserted from the trigger, you shouldn't need to select from the table. The key is that bit about selecting from Inserted. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355921/sql-server-2008-help-writing-simple-insert-trigger/1355953#1355953