# how to check for new table entry in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to check for new table entry in MySql?
I need to automate the task in java so every time a new row added to the table the scrip that I am writing give me alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INSERT trigger.

Here is a Stackoverflow article: [SQL Server 2008 - Help writing simple INSERT Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355921/sql-server-2008-help-writing-simple-insert-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer link below for you reference

http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/get-an-alert-when-a-certain-record-changes/