# SQL SERVER AFTER INSERT TRIGGER TO INSERT NON-ZERO VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a insert trigger on a table called Client1  to insert non-zero values  into a table called Client2.

For example, when inserting the values below into Client1 table

```
Client_ID  CATEGORY1  CATEGORY2  CATEGORY3   CATEGORY4 CATEGORY5
 6000          1          0         1            0          0
```

It will trigger to insert values into Client2 table:

```
INSERT INTO Client2 (Client_ID, Category_type,Value)
VALUES (6000, CATEGORY1, 1)

INSERT INTO Client2 (Client_ID, Category_type,Value)
VALUES (6000, CATEGORY3, 1)
```

Can anyone help with it? Thanks.

Comment: First, you should probably think about changing your data structure so that you do not have the category columns on this table at all.  Instead have a lookup with Id, Client_Id, Category_Id.  When your application creates a client have it insert into your Client1 table, and then also do an Insert into your Client_Category_Lookup for each category that applies.   If you just want to do a trigger,  write the trigger as if the category value is 1, then wrap the whole thing in an IF(CategoryX = 1).  You'll need to repeat the IF() INSERT for each category with your current data structure.

Comment: Here is an example of how to write a trigger.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355921/sql-server-2008-help-writing-simple-insert-trigger -- you'll need to also look up how to write an IF statement in SQL if you are unfamiliar.

Comment: I want to do a trigger because Client1 table is a staging table. Do you know how to avoid to repeat the if() Insert for each category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, which unpivots your data into a more usable format for inserting then does so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourTrigger ON Client1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Client2 (Client_ID, Category_Type, Value)
SELECT Client_ID, Category_Type, Value
FROM inserted
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CATEGORY1,'CATEGORY1'), 
                    (CATEGORY2,'CATEGORY2'), 
                    (CATEGORY3,'CATEGORY3'), 
                    (CATEGORY4,'CATEGORY4'), 
                    (CATEGORY5,'CATEGORY5')) C (Value, Category_Type)
WHERE Value <> 0
END
```

You mentioned this is transforming data from a staging table.. Consider putting this in a procedure and calling that, instead of having the trigger fire on every insert.

Comment: Schema: client1 (Client_ID int, Category1 int, Category2 int, Category3 int, Category4 int, Category5 int)  should you change "SELECT Client_ID, Category_Type, Value FROM inserted"
in your SQL?  Thanks,

Comment: I mean inserted table should have the same schema as Client1 table which I sent to you earlier. So I don't understand  'SELECT Client_ID, Category_Type, Value FROM inserted' . Are you converting client1 (Client_ID int, Category1 int, Category2 int, Category3 int, Category4 int, Category5 int) to the schema of Client2 table using unpivot?

Comment: @Ice Ahh, then yes exactly.  `Category_Type` and `Value` are the output of the unpivot which happens on `inserted`.  It saves you from writing a long list of `if`s and probably a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query statement.

```
CREATE TABLE Client1 (ClintId INT, Category1 INT, Category2 INT,Category3 INT,Category4 INT,Category5 INT)

CREATE TABLE Client2(ClientId INT, CategoryType VARCHAR(100),VALUE INT)

GO
ALTER TRIGGER SampleTrigger  
ON Client1  
AFTER INSERT
AS  
    DECLARE @ClientID INT
    DECLARE @Category1 AS INT
    DECLARE @Category2 AS INT
    DECLARE @Category3 AS INT
    DECLARE @Category4 AS INT
    DECLARE @Category5 AS INT

    SELECT @ClientID = ClintId, @Category1= Category1, @Category2= Category2, 
    @Category3= Category3, @Category4 =Category4, @Category5= Category5 FROM inserted

    IF(@Category1<>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client2(ClientId,CategoryType,Value) VALUES(@ClientID,'Category1',@Category1)
    END
    IF(@Category2<>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client2(ClientId,CategoryType,Value) VALUES(@ClientID,'Category2',@Category2)
    END
    IF(@Category3<>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client2(ClientId,CategoryType,Value) VALUES(@ClientID,'Category3',@Category3)
    END
    IF(@Category4<>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client2(ClientId,CategoryType,Value) VALUES(@ClientID,'Category4',@Category4)
    END
    IF(@Category5<>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Client2(ClientId,CategoryType,Value) VALUES(@ClientID,'Category5',@Category5)
    END
```

After inserting the following values,you can see the effect on Client2 table

```
INSERT INTO Client1(ClintId, Category1, Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5)
VALUES(6000,1,0,1,0,0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Ice,If you got really help from this, please mark as a answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AaronDietz, I have checked again it is working fine for multiple rows. Thanks.

Comment: Let's say you insert 3 rows at once.  The trigger fires once, but it can't set the `@category` variables to 3 different values.  With a `SET @category =` it would literally fail with a "subquery returned more then 1 value" error, but with the `SELECT @category =` it will appear to succeed.  However, if you look at `client2` table, you will see that it only inserted one clientID's set of rows, whichever is chosen as the top row when the variables are populated.